# Implementing following stream

Tags: redis

I am developing an app for photo sharing and having follow system so whosoever follow x user then x users photo will come in his following .

I am storing my data in redis as following

```
sadd rdis_key+user_id photo_id
set redis_key+photo_id+data data_of_photo
sadd redis_key+follow+user_id follower_id
```

Now I want to get directly all photo_id of followers without looping.

Comment: what do you store inside `data_of_photo`? Do you think it is a good idea using `Redis` as a data store for your application? Consider MongoDB with its [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) :)

Comment: @n9code I understand i can store data in MongoDB but that's not problem. How can i get photo_is of followers . That is what I am looking

Comment: Just suggesting. The problem with redis is that you cannot make queries there. Your options are either Lua or implement your query on your client side.

Comment: I am using Lua but then i have to run loop over all follower and get photo_id of theirs . Which i don't want, is there any thing with redis exist. Thats what I am asking

Comment: I don't think there is a possible way to achieve your goal without a loop in Redis :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple fan-out problem which you can not easily do with Redis directly.

You can do it with Lua but YOU WILL block Redis during the action.

I have an open source project which does the same thing but I do it in code as someone creates a new post. I would imagine this is just like a new photo.

https://github.com/pjuu/pjuu/blob/master/pjuu/posts/backend.py#L252

I use sorted sets though and use the unix timestamp as the score so they are always in order.

As User1 creates a new photo you look up a list of their followers. If you are using a sorted set you can get this via:

`followers = zrange followers:user1 0 -1`

then simply loop over all entries in that list:

`for follower in followers: zadd feed:user2 <timestamp> <photo_id>`

This way this new post is now pushed out to all users that are follow user1.

If you want this done on the fly then bad news: You will need some relational data and a way to query in the values which you can't do. SQL, Mongo, Couch, etc...

This is only pseudo code as you did not mention which language you use.

EDIT: As per question this is to be done on the Redis side

```
local followers = redis.call('zrange', KEYS[1], 0, -1)

for key, value in pairs(followers) do
    redis.call('zadd', 'items:'..value, ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
end

return true
```

This will take a key of the users followers to iterate over. A zset score and value and will add these to the items for each user. You will need to change it to suit your exact needs. If you want to use sets you will need to use sscan or something. Zsets are easier though and in order.

Comment: Joe Thats what i don't want. Please look my previous comments. I don't want loop it. Looping makes it slow..

Comment: When I'm at a computer I will post a lua version. It may be slower but blocking Redis for that long is going to make it appear even more slow if more users try to perform other commands during this time. If it does not have to be instant you can defer the fan out to a worker as to not block anything up

Comment: I've added a Lua example of what you could do.

Comment: thanks a lot . But i am doing same thing currently but it is slow . I am planning to move to  stream framework.